# Resource Reservation for SP 2013 on prem

Tags: 2013, resources

I wanted to know what others are using for reserving various office resources (rooms, equipments, etc). This is for Sharepoint 2013 on-prem. You may be aware that MS had discontinued support for group calendars which was a very good feature in my opinion that allowed us to create resource reservation calendars.

I wanted to know what others are using for the alternative.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this feature in SharePoint 2013 as well. For this you have to -

> migrate your application with installed booking calendar from
>   SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and you will keep functionality of
>   resource reservation but you cannot activate it on a new SharePoint
>   2013 application through default interface.

and in case you are using SharePoint online then you can upload a sand-boxed solution which enables the " Group Work Lists " feature for you.

found a code project link which describes this steps.

[hope this is useful via code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588685/ReservationplusofplusresourcesplusinplusSharePoint)

Comment: Thanks @Vishwas, but we are not migrating any existing reservation calendar from 2010 and dont have any immediate plan to move on to SP online. Thanks for the code project link, it will be handy when we move to SP online. I was interested to know of any third party product some of you may be using for the 2013 on-prem.

Comment: My pleasure @Amir. 

i will let you know if i get any such third party product

Answer (score 0):

First thing:

> Existing sites that were created by using the Group Work site template
>   will continue to operate in SharePoint 2013. The Group Work site
>   template will be removed completely from the next major release of
>   SharePoint and sites that were created by using the Group Work site
>   template will not be supported.

This template is still available in the 2013 for the backward compatibility( in order to support the 2010 migrated sites), But still you can enable that template to use in 2013 but keep in mind will not available in SharePoint 2016.

- Go to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
  Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\1033\XML`
- open **WEBTEMP.XML** file
- find an element with '**Group Work Site**' title attribute and change its
  Hidden attribute from **FALSE** to **TRUE**.

Read this: [Reservation of resources in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2013 Online in Office 365](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/reservation-of-resources-in-sharepoint-2013-and-sharepoint-2013)

[Features at a Glance Room Manager 2013](http://www.acar.ch/solutions/Pages/Room-Manager-2013-Feature.aspx)

Comment: shouldnt the Hidden attribute be set to False? I am aware of this hack and tried both TRUE and FALSE recently and the group work template is not appearing on the features page. It did appear some months ago, but not coming up any more. I think the recent updates really hammered in the final nail into the group calendar coffin.